# Explicit Dynamic ANSYS - Origami structure

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, dynamics, simulation, ansys

I am working on a flat-foldable conical structure and I would like to carry out some dynamic tests on it (deployment to get the displacements and accelerations...).

I have designed the folded geometry of this conical structure on Soliworks. This CAD file (geometry) is composed of a significant number of surperimposed surfaces bodies (triangular facets). Obtaining this file is quite complicated and involves a equations and relations.

I tried to use Ansys Workbench and the module Explicit Dynamic, but I have a two issues to figure out and I don't know whether it is possible.
First, when I import the CAD geometry in Ansys Workbench, the MechanicalDesign module recognizes connections between the superimposed surfaces but not between the edges of the facets. I do want any connection between the surfaces so I simply deleted them, but I do know how to create relation between the edges. I do not know if there is a way to fix this.

Does anybody has an idea or better solution to carry out this test ? As a student in Engineering school in another department than Structure and Material, I have only a basic background in the field of Finite Element and simulation.

Secondly, my CAD file approximate (10^-15) the angles and lengths of the surfaces bodies (facets) and I know it can have an impact on the deployment of structure at the initial position...

Comment: Could you add a picture of your structure + edge restraints?